# sum of character product over derangements

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, permutation-groups

It is widely known that 
$$ \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\chi_\lambda(\pi)\chi_\mu(\pi)=\delta_{\lambda,\mu},$$
where $S_n$ is the permutation group and $\chi$ are its irreducible characters.

In exercise 7.63 of his classic book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, Richard Stanley computes explicitly the value of
$$\sum_{\pi\in D_n}\chi_\lambda(\pi),$$
where $\lambda$ is a hook and $D_n$ is the set of derangements (permutations without fixed points).

I would like to know the value of $$ \sum_{\pi\in D_n}\chi_\lambda(\pi)\chi_\mu(\pi),$$
at least when $\lambda$ and/or $\mu$ is a hook. Is anything known about this sum? (It is a generalization of the previous one, to which it reduces when $\mu=(n)$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I can? If I decompose $\chi_\lambda\chi_\mu=\sum_\rho c_\rho \chi_\rho$ now the $\rho$'s are not necessarily hooks so the formula of Stanley does not help.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully enough to see that Stanley's computation was just for hooks- I was thinking it worked for all $\lambda.$

Comment: On the other hand, maybe Stanley's result, together with the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule, is enough to do the general $\lambda.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Maybe a bit more detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using standard symmetric function notation, we have
  \begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{\lambda,\mu\vdash n}
     \frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{\pi\in D_n}\chi_\lambda(\pi)\chi_\mu(\pi)\right)
     s_\lambda(x)s_\mu(y) & = & \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}
     \sum_{\pi\in S_n}\left.p_{\rho(\pi)}(x)p_{\rho(\pi)}(y)\right|_{p_1(x)=0}\\
     & = & \sum_\nu \left.s_\nu(x)s_\nu(y)\right|_{p_1(x)=0}\\
     & = & e^{-p_1(x)p_1(y)}\sum_\nu s_\nu(x)s_\nu(y),
  \end{eqnarray*}
since
  $$\sum_\nu s_\nu(x)s_\nu(y)=\exp \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac
      {p_m(x)p_m(y)}{m}. $$
Thus your sum is obtained by expanding $e^{-p_1(x)p_1(y)}\sum_\nu
  s_\nu(x)s_\nu(y)$ in terms of Schur functions and taking
  $n!$ times the coefficient of $s_\lambda(x)s_\mu(y)$. To do this
  expansion you could write
    $$ e^{-p_1(x)p_1(y)} = \sum_{m\geq 0}
  (-1)^m\frac{s_1(x)^ms_1(y)^m}{m!} $$
and iteratively apply Pieri's formula for multiplying a Schur
function by $s_1$.

Comment: This looks very good indeed, thank you.